# Logic: evenb_double_conv

Tags: coq, logical-foundations

```
Theorem evenb_double_conv : forall n,
  exists k, n = if evenb n then double k
                else S (double k).
Proof.
  (* Hint: Use the [evenb_S] lemma from [Induction.v]. *)
  intros n. induction n as [|n' IHn'].
  - simpl. exists O. simpl. reflexivity.
  - rewrite -> evenb_S. destruct (evenb n') as [H1 | H2].
    + simpl.
```

Here I am stuck:

```
n' : nat
IHn' : exists k : nat, n' = double k
============================
exists k : nat, S n' = S (double k)
```

We can either rewrite (double k) to n' using inductive hypothesis or use injection upon the goal and then apply induction hypothesis.

But I can do none of these because of `exists`.

`rewrite <- IHn'` gives:

> Error: Cannot find an homogeneous relation to rewrite.

`injection` gives:

> Error: Ltac call to "injection" failed.
>         Not a negated primitive equality.

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to break `exists` in hypothesis with destruct: `destruct IHn' as [k HE].`

```
Theorem evenb_double_conv : forall n,
  exists k, n = if evenb n then double k
                else S (double k).
Proof.
  (* Hint: Use the [evenb_S] lemma from [Induction.v]. *)
  intros n. induction n as [|n' IHn'].
  - simpl. exists O. simpl. reflexivity.
  - rewrite -> evenb_S. destruct IHn' as [k HE].  destruct (evenb n').
    (* Now find out which k we need to insert into the goal for every branch *)
```

Injection doesn't work here, because it works only in hypothesis.

Comment: Isn't this the answer to an exercise given in a course?  Does it make sense to publish the answer?

Comment: @Yves While keeping the hint for the hard part, I removed the last part of the solution.